# Principal curvature and enclosed volume of surface

Tags: riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

In 46 page of 
*Huisken, Gerhard*, [**The volume preserving mean curvature flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/crll.1987.382.35), J. Reine Angew. Math. 382, 35-48 (1987). [ZBL0621.53007](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0621.53007).

Assume $M\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is a n-dim compact  smooth convex manifold without boundary, if the volume enclosed by $M$ is constant, how to show the principal curvature of $M$ can't tend to infinity? In fact, I think it is wrong, for example, in the picture below, the max principle curvature tend to infinity.

> [image]

Besides, whether there are  upper lower estimate of volume by the curvature of manifold?

Comment: I don't think you are quoting the paper correctly. For starters, the $M$ in Huisken's paper is uniformly convex...

Comment: @WillieWong I have edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you: write 
$$\mbox{Vol}(\Omega)=\int_{M}\int_{0}^{c(p)}\prod(1-t\lambda_i)dtdA,$$
where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a compact convex domain which $\partial\Omega=M$,  $\lambda_i$ are the principal curvatures of $M$, $dA$ is the area of $M$, $c(p)=\max\left\{t\geq 0:\mbox{dist}(M,\mbox{exp}(t\nu_p)\right\}$ and $\nu_p$ is the upward unit normal of $M$ at $p$.

Then, by convexity, $c(p)\leq\lambda_{\mbox{max}}^{-1}$ and the result will follow.

Comment: Thanks, where I can find its proof ?

Comment: Here http://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=0213-2230&vol=3&iss=3&rank=8